# Calculate the difference between two dates of format (YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM) and display results in minutes

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Using moment js, I'm trying this. I couldn't able to resolve this.

```
const dateOne = "2021-03-08 16:45"
const dateTwo = "2021-03-08 17:45"
console.log(moment.duration(dateTwo.diff(dateOne)));
```

Comment: This looks like it should work, are you getting any errors?

Comment: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/diffing/

Comment: You didn't initialize your dates with `moment` - `dateTwo.diff` will throw a TypeError.

Comment: @fortunee I'm not getting any errors

Comment: Yeah, I figured. See my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider changing the dates to `moment` objects by wrapping the strings like this

```js
const dateOne = moment("2021-03-08 16:45")
const dateTwo = moment("2021-03-08 17:45");

const duration = moment.duration(dateTwo.diff(dateOne));
console.log(duration.asHours());
```

Comment: Yes this works fine after wrapping it to moment objects. duration.asMinutes() displays the results in min

Answer (score -1):

Well there are a couple of issues that you're having:

- There is no 'diff' property in JS strings (I think you're trying to use moment dates)
- Moment is no longer being developed because of similar issues you're having

My recommendation would be to migrate to Luxon (the recommended Moment.js alternatives by the Moment.js team). They provide a .diff function for their DateTime objects - [https://moment.github.io/luxon/docs/class/src/datetime.js~DateTime.html](https://moment.github.io/luxon/docs/class/src/datetime.js%7EDateTime.html)

What you'll need to do is create a DateTime object for dateOne and dateTwo and then use [this function](https://moment.github.io/luxon/docs/class/src/datetime.js%7EDateTime.html#instance-method-diff) to get the difference (from which you can get the minutes)

**Edit**:

Just so you know, Moment.js [does recommend](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/) moving away from it if you can or are building a new project